# Laravel 7 - Empty Eloquent Model object right after persisting if via Create method

Tags: laravel, eloquent, mariadb

When creating a new model via Eloquent like this:

```
$appUser = AppUser::create([
    'id' => Str::uuid(),
    'name' => $request->name,                
    'location' => new Point(rand(0,90), rand(0,180))
 ]);
```

and, in the same request, I access the object like this...:

```
$location = $appUser->location;
$name     = $appUser->name; //I can get this from the request, but I have lots of random fields generated for test users and it's much more convenient if I could just access the created properties, including the default ones.
```

...then, sometimes, the properties are empty (when this happens, all properties are empty and the id is `0`). It's like the database doesn't have enough time to create the object before it's accessed that way.

I tried issuing a `refresh()` before accessing the properties, but this `$appUser->refresh()` will throw the following error sometimes:

```
Unknown error: No query results for model [App\Models\AppUser]
```

That also points in the direction that the object is not yet persisted. But why does the PHP thread continue to execute if the object is not persisted (MariaDB 5.6, PHP 7.4)?

EDIT:
The AppUser model:

```
class AppUser extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
      'id',
      'name',
      'location'
    ];

    protected $casts = [
      'id' => 'string'
    ];
```

}

The schema:

```
Schema::create('app_users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->uuid('id')->primary()->unique();
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->boolean('active')->default(true);
    $table->string('name', 128);
    $table->geometry('location')->nullable();
});
```

Comment: Is `id` in your `AppUser` Model's `fillable` array? Typically, `id`s are auto-incrementing, and ignored even if included in `::create()`, but I don't recall if that is the default for Models or not. You seem to be using `uuids`, which is fine if configured correctly. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75856616/edit) and include your `AppUser` Model, and your migration for your `app_users` Table (or whatever it's called)

Comment: Excellent; everything looks correct to me, but I haven't worked with uuids in MariaDB  specifically before (but I assume it should be the same or similar to MySQL's implementation). And you say this is an intermittent issue, i.e. it doesn't happen all the time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your model is still looking for an auto-increment value for `ID` (integer) in database, but you have an `UUID` there.

> Eloquent will also assume that each model's corresponding database
> table has a primary key column named id. If necessary, you may define
> a protected $primaryKey property on your model to specify a different
> column that serves as your model's primary key. In addition, Eloquent assumes that the primary key is an incrementing integer value, which means that Eloquent will automatically cast the primary key to an integer.

In order to use `UUID` as your primary key, you have to add two properties to your model:

```
public $incrementing = false;
protected $keyType = 'char';
```

You find more info about incrementing and key type [here](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#primary-keys).

Comment: Not user this is the case. The app works fine except when trying to query freshly created models (during the same request). Would that be the case in this scenario?

Comment: I had the same problem while ago, and this fixed the issue. If is still not working fro you, maybe you can refresh the model: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#refreshing-models

Comment: Not sure why but setting the $keyType and $incrementing seems to have done the trick. I suspect there's something else going on though. Since it works now, I won't touch it ; )